# pointInside:withEvent inside uibezierpath (overlapping area between two views)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, uibezierpath

no matter how much I tried I couldn't have access (Handle scrolling/Touchevents) to the overlapping area (right triangle) between two square shaped views A and B (A in on top of B)as shown in this image

[image]

I want the right part (triangle B) with is defined by UIbezierpath to handle the scrolling for the view beneath it(which is B). I couldn't have access to it by `pointInside: withEvent:` since its a bezierpath. 
Even `touchesBegan:withEvent:` didn't work at all

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([leftPath containsPoint:touchPoint])
    {  //Do something
     }
 }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement hitTest method of UIView to detect touch on particular view. Simply subclass your View and implement hitTest method.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

if ([path containsPoint:point]){

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
else{

    return nil;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `hitTest: withEvent` now gets called when i touch the view itself but how can i make the rest of the view (overlapping section with the view beneath it) become transparent so the view beneath it gets my touch (scrolling etc)??

Comment: Are you trying to make shape for  PhotoCollage Application ?

Comment: I did it by defining two separate views, subclassing uiview and each having a triangular mask, implementing `hitTest:withEvent:` and `point:withEvent` only on the top view and then adding a subview of another uiview in them which they subclass the uiview and override methods for pinch,pan etc. thank you, now touch  events work on both views. I also tried to use `topView.layer.zPosition = 0.1; `and `downView.layer.zPosition = 0;` to make sure ;)